# Paytm checksum mismatch - Android Paytm SDK Error: 330

Tags: android, payment, checksum, paytm

This may be possibly duplicates of other questions, I checked on every where for solutions, But didn't find right solution for this Paytm checksum mismatch.

i am getting checksum mismatch error in paytm to android app i have created check sum in php(On my Server) and sending from server to android app.once app received checksum then this parameters along with checksum will go to server to verify check sum and for payment.

I am receiving following response:

```
[{STATUS=TXN_FAILURE, CHECKSUMHASH="***", ORDERID=e5992c72f44648799e034df284f4f339, TXNAMOUNT=100.00, MID=222, RESPCODE=330, BANKTXNID=, CURRENCY=INR, RESPMSG=Paytm checksum mismatch.}]
```

This is Request data:

```
 {
    "CALLBACK_URL":"https://securegw.paytm.in/theia/paytmCallback?ORDER_ID=d53a1edd5f8fb46539c793476700b576c",
    "CHANNEL_ID":"WAP",
    "CUST_ID":"0fbfd97306a748298477aa7c11fb8040",
    "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID":"Retail",
    "MID":"myMID",
    "ORDER_ID":"53a1edd5f8fb46539c793476700b576c",
    "TXN_AMOUNT":"100",
    "WEBSITE":"APPSTAGING"
    }
```

I have also checked issue on Android Paytm, but i didn't find any solution for this. kindly note that i am using same parameters on both side (App & Web).

Your small suggestions can help me a lot!!

Thanks.

Comment: share your code with staging values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I faced the same Issue. I sent proper data from app for creating checksum to My server. But server was creating checksum with different values. So I received "Checksum mismatch error". You can also do cross-check from your app and your server keys. server url & parameters that both side you are using same parameters values.

By doing this i solved my issue. Hope this agenda will help you also.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You save my day!

Comment: I have same values still not able resolve the issue

Comment: You can also do cross-check from your app and your server keys.

Comment: I checked with both app and server keys but still i am getting "RESPMSG":"Invalid checksum" only. Can you please help me?

Comment: @ssowri1 make sure in your app and web both have same data parameters used for creating checksum. Do Cross check. Read my answer slowly and try to find out mismatched data in your app and web. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION**
I spent almost 2 days to searching for solution nothing worked, I cloned some working examples and realized that i was appending extra parameters hence removed them one by one to test and boom I got the payment screen.

Solution : Remove all extraParams in genchecksum params eg: PAYTM_FINAL_URL.
My Params object

```
let paytmParams = {
    "ORDER_ID": shortid.generate(),
    "CUST_ID": shortid.generate(),
    "INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID": paytmConfig.INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID,
    "CHANNEL_ID": paytmConfig.CHANNEL_ID,
    "TXN_AMOUNT": TXN_AMOUNT.toString(),
    "MID": paytmConfig.MID,
    "WEBSITE": paytmConfig.WEBSITE,
    "CALLBACK_URL": paytmConfig.CALLBACK_URL,
    "MOBILE_NO": MOBILE_NO,
    "EMAIL": EMAIL,
}
```